# Redirect regex misbehaving when placeholder empty

Tags: wp-redirect, regex, redirect

I have the following 2 redirects active:

```
/code-examples/(.*)
-> /tutorials/android/$1/
```

and

```
/code-examples/android/(.*)
-> /tutorials/android/$1/
```

The first one has a higher position, so the second will only be executed if the first one didn't apply. This works if there is something in the placeholders, i.e. `/code-examples/page1` leads to `/tutorials/android/page1`.

The problems occur when the placeholders are empty.
Just `/code-examples` or `/code-examples/android` WITHOUT the trailing slash leads to 404. With the trailing slash, I can see that it adds a second slash at the end, which results in `/tutorials/android//`.

How can I get the redirects to work properly with and without something in the placeholders?

Comment: Where are these redirects? .htaccess?

Comment: Your code can be combined: `/code-examples(?:/android|)(?:/?(.*)|\b)` And the problem with your REGEX is because it's "requiring" the `/` (slash) at the end. Btw, this question would have probably been better asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you! Will the regex you posted solve my problem? Looks hella complicated

Comment: And I added the redirects with the Redirection plugin. I am a noob.

Comment: @FlorianWalther Yes, it will. Check my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The problem with your RegEx patterns:

  ```
  /code-examples/(.*)
  /code-examples/android/(.*)
  ```

  is that they only match when the ending slash (`/`) is present in the URL; e.g.:

  ```
  # Example 1: $1 is 'page1'
  /code-examples/page1
  /code-examples/android/page1

  # Example 2: $1 is '' (empty)
  /code-examples/
  /code-examples/android/

  # Example 3
  # No matches because the ending / is not present.
  /code-examples
  /code-examples/android
  ```

  where the "placeholder" (i.e. `(.*)`) matches the `page1` in the first example, and `''` (i.e. empty string) in the second example.
- To make these work:

  ```
  /code-examples
  /code-examples/android
  ```

  you can use `(?:/?(.*)|\b)` instead of `/(.*)`, like so:

  ```
  /code-examples(?:/?(.*)|\b)
  /code-examples/android(?:/?(.*)|\b)
  ```
- But since you redirect to the *same URL* (`/tutorials/android/$1/`), you can combine those RegEx patterns like so:

  ```
  /code-examples(?:/android|)(?:/?(.*)|\b)
  ```

  where `/code-examples(?:/android|)` matches either `/code-examples` or `/code-examples/android`.

> I added the redirects with the Redirection plugin.

I suppose you have something like this on the *Tools → Redirection → Redirects* page (in `wp-admin`):

[image]

Now with the combined RegEx pattern, delete the second Redirect and edit the first one like so:

[image]

*Note: For the Type and Group settings, just use your existing setup.*

**Resources:**

- Redirect Regular Expressions: https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/
- https://regexr.com/41vch — for testing the combined RegEx pattern. But note that on RegExr, you need to use `\/` and not just `/`. I.e. escape the `/` with a `\`.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped you. :)